# why doesnt my button work on addEventListener alongside Ejs and Express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I tried to make a Twitter-shaped place where I can make tweets(posts) and the posts display on the same page. also, each post has an Edit  that is display:none as default. When I push the Edit button I need to change that display to Block so I could make it visible and edit my comment using that space.
But my button won't work!
i wanted to test my button so i put a console.log for its Event but it doesnt work. why?

it would be great if you could help me with my problem and also suggest ways to achieve my ultimate goal(making comments and editing them in the same place).
index.js(first code)/
home.ejs(second code)

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');`enter code here`
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
    let allPosts = [];

    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended :true }));
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

    app.get('/',(req,res) => {
        res.render('home.ejs')
    })

    app.post('/post/new',(req,res) => {
        const {username,post} = req.body;
        allPosts.push({username,post});
        res.render('home.ejs',{allPosts});
    })


    app.listen(3000,() => {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 3000!')
    })
```

---

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the Wall!</h1>
        <p>tell me whats on your mind today!</p>
        <form action="/post/new" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name='username' placeholder="username">
            <textarea name='post' placeholder="how do you feel today?"></textarea>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <% for (p in locals.allPosts) { %>
            <% let post = locals.allPosts  %> 
            <p>
                <b><%= post[p].username %></b> : <%= post[p].post %> 
                <button class="edit">Edit</button><button>Delete</button>
            </p>
            <textarea id="edit" name="edit" style='display:none'></textarea>
        <% } %>
        <script>
            let edit = document.querySelector('.edit');
            edit.addEventListener('click',() => {
            console.log('you clicked on edit btn!');})

        </script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('#edit')` selects the unique element with the ID `edit`.

The element which has that ID is a `textarea`, not a `button` and it is generated in a loop so it probably isn't unique.

If you want to select an element based on the classes it is a member of, use `.` not `#` and don't put special characters (like `#`) in the classname itself.

If you want to select multiple elements, use `querySelectorAll` and loop over the multiple results it gives.

Comment: i tried it with class names and it wouldnt still work.

Comment: @mamalatishi — You ignored the last paragraph of this answer, so you're only selecting the first element that is a member of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button attribute to id.Like following.

```
 <button id="edit">Edit</button><button>Delete</button>
```

And then i your script

```
 let edit = document.querySelector('#edit');
```